# Database creation in Android using Command Prompt?

Tags: android, database, command-prompt

Is there any possible to create database for android using Command Prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using the [sqlite3](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite) tool from a shell.